# stuck in using jquery filter in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

With only using js I'm able to select 4,6 and 8.

The challenge is when I hover an item, but not the first, then I need to output/alert 3,5,7.
When I hover a value inside the output, I need to exclude this from the output.
For example I hover 1, then nothing happens.
If I hover 2, then it outputs/alerts 3,5,7.
If I hover 3, then it outputs/alerts 5,7 because 3 is one of these values.

```js
$('.item').filter(function (index) {
    return index > 2 && index % 2 == 1
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
```

Comment: Can you post some code for what you've tried?

Comment: What are you trying to do? make 3, 5 and 7 bold? What's exclude enable?  What hover are you trying to do?  The question is quite hard tyo understand what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```js
// index starts from 0, so to select odd numbers you need to check with == 0
$('.item').filter(function (index) {
    // If you don't wan't 9 bold add && index < 8
    return index > 1 && index % 2 == 0;
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
```

Comment: for filter is looping?

Comment: filter function is traversing all items and returns only those which are returning true, so you could say it's an loop

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(".item:gt(0)").hover(function () {

    var currentIndex = $(this).index();
    var oddEvent = currentIndex % 2;
    $('.item').removeClass("test");

    $('.item').filter(function (index) {
        return index % 2 == oddEvent && index > 0;
    }).addClass("test");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/w0nnxw75/8/)

Comment: @user3522892 Sorry . i read it again ,i could not understand your problem .could you explain clearly again  ...

Answer (score 0):

You should select all items except first `:not(:first)`.

Then you the items with values of 3,5,7

```
$('.item').filter(function (index) {
    return index > 2 && index % 2 == 1
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Iterate over these values and if value equals the value you hover then don't add it to your text field.

```js
$('.item').filter(function (index) {
    return index > 2 && index % 2 == 1
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');

$('.item:not(:first)').mouseover(function() {
    var text ="";
    var itemval = $(this).text();
    items = $('.item').filter(function (index) {
        return index > 1 && index % 2 == 0 && index < 8
    })
    $.each(items, function(i,val){
        var value =  $(val).text();
        if( value != itemval ){
            text += value + ' ';
        }
   });
   $('.answer').text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
<div class="answer"></div>
```